# How to Log, the URL I am accessing retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, logging, retrofit

I am using retrofit to communicate with the BE and I want to the log the URL i am hitting and the body I am sending and the response I am getting (like 401, 404).

This is to know if I am hitting the right url what is the header, body and the actual URL to verify I am sending all the right info required

I implemented HttpLoggingInterceptor but that does not log it, or I am logging it the right way

can you suggest please.

```
object RetrofitBuilder {
    private const val BASE_URL = "https://xxxx.xxxxxx.com/"

    private fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        var interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build() //Doesn't require the adapter
    }

    val apiService: ApiService = getRetrofit().create(ApiService::class.java)
}
```

AppService

```
@POST
    suspend fun postData(@Url url: String, @Body Data: Data, @Header("Autzn") authHeader: String)
```

ApiHelper

//NOTE: here i am using the different URL as but not the baseUrl defined on the top

```
apiService.postData("https://abcd.com/msg/oauth2/123456", Data,
            "token")

//Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.1'
```

Please suggest how to log the url info

thanks
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just give **HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger** interface.

logging interceptor should be like this.

```
   val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor(object : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {
            override fun log(message: String) {
                Timber.tag("retrofit").d(message)
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 1):

This is How I'm logging url in logs

```
val retrofitApi: RetrofitInterface
        get() {
            if (retrofitInterface == null) {
                val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                logger.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .addInterceptor(logger).build()


                val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(REST_HOST)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder()
                                .setLenient()
                                .create()))
                        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                        .client(okHttpClient)
                        .build()
                retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface::class.java)
            }
            return this.retrofitInterface!!
        }
```

Comment: Hello Chand thank you for getting back. do you do anything else after writing this code to log, or it automatically logs it. and how do u see the logs, what tags should i use to spot it

Comment: and do you think my code is wrong? I cannot spot where I got it wrong

Comment: NO `HttpLoggingInterceptor` will take care logging  and you are code seems fine to me . This is how I'm logging ervery api url

Comment: yeah for some reason it does not log, but when i gave HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger  as Deniz suggested it worked fine, thank you very much for ur input

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `HttpLoggingInterceptor` with **log level**, logging can be heavy task especially with images(printing raw bytes), and with big images(40mb+) can throw OOM exception.

So use logging for debug purpose.

```
public HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor
                = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> Log.d(TAG, message));
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
        return loggingInterceptor;
    }
```